# Understanding constructor/inheritance syntax in C++ struct

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++, having come from Python and some previous experience with C, and came across some syntax in a tutorial for `struct` that I am having difficulty understanding since it concerns constructors and inheritance not present in C. The lines in question are indicated below with `Line 1` and `Line 2`

```cpp
enum class ObjectType {
  STRING,
  NUMBER,
};

struct Object {
  Object(ObjectType type) : type(type) {}  // Line 1
  ObjectType type;
};

struct StrObject : public Object {
  StrObject(const std::string &str) : Object(ObjectType::STRING), string(str) {} // Line 2
  std::string string;
};
```

At `Line 1`, I understand this is the constructor for the `Object` struct which accepts a value from the `ObjectType` enum as argument argument which it refers to as `type`. What I don't quite understand is what is happening in the remaining `: type(type) {}`.

Similarly at `Line 2`, this is the constructor for the `StrObject` struct which accepts a reference to a string as its argument and calls it `str`. Again, the syntax that follows I'm struggling to understand `: Object(ObjectType::STRING), string(str) {}`.

I assume what is happening at `Line 2` is `Object(ObjectType::STRING)` is calling the constructor of the parent struct with the `STRING` enum value which, in `Line 1`, is being set to the `type` member variable via the `type(type)` bit? Similarly, in `Line 2`, `string(str)` is setting the value of the `string` member variable to whatever is passed into the constructor when the `StrObject` is instantiated.

Assuming the above is correct interpretation, why does this happen before the function body `{}` and not within as is the case for classes in other languages (e.g. python, javascript, etc.)?

Comment: Check this - [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).

Comment: Suggest to take a book from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @LouisGo Re: _"It's for const member variables"_ - It's for _all_ non-`static` member variables.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Would `it's required for initializing const member variables` be more precise?

Comment: @LouisGo It's required in those cases the `const` member can't be initialized by other means, like via in-class initialization.

Comment: @LouisGo That interpretation is like saying the `= 42` part of `const int x = 42;` is there for the purpose of initializing const variables. It is correct, but also so incomplete that it misleadingl. That is a way to initialize *all* non-static data members, it just so happens that const data members are more restricted and rely on it more than non-const data members.